# Ajax and SEO. Will my loading part of the html be indexed by SE?

Tags: ajax, seo

So, I have an index.html file. 
I load some div from another.html file like so: a href="another.html" 
Then, in jQ, I'm using .preventDefault(); on this anchor tag before .load


Will my another.html file be indexed by Google, Yahoo and so on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, they way you did this is called [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and is how dynamic website *should* be built as it allows for non-JavaScript enabled users to still get to the content. Good job.